# How to add buttons and enable tap on UIContextMenu previewView on iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, contextmenu, tap, uicontextmenuinteraction

I am trying to add some buttons on the previewView for context menu. But on tapping the preview View, the content menu gets dismissed. How to disable the dismiss action and detect tap on the button inside preview view?
I tried setting `UserInteractionEnabled` for the preview view, but that didn't help.
I need to add a button in the red area and it should be clickable.

[image]

Comment: Nobody even knows what a guy you so-call 'previewView' or 'preview View' is.

Comment: @ElTomato Added the image. PreviewView means the view that we give via previewProvider for contextMenu.